# SQL column values must exist in both tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want Get the Courses the Student with ID 444111110 can register.
Course that can be registered is courses with no prerequisite or courses with 
prerequisite he already took and scored a grade in it.

Course the student withdraw must be showed as well, so he can register again. It will be given 'W' in grade column
Courses the student takes and courses he took must not be showed.
it will be given 'U' in grade column if he is already taking this course.

```
#COURSE_ID   PREREQUISITE_COURSE_ID
CS111        NULL
CS211        CS111
CS244        CS311
CS244        CS211
CS244        CS111
CS311        CS211
CS311        CS111

# STUDENT_ID  COURSE_ID  DATEREGISTERED  EnrollToken  GREADE
444111110     CS111      2005-03-10      5            A
444111110     CS211      2005-03-10      7            A+
444111111     CS111      2005-03-10      6            W

# COURSE_ID  COURSE_NAME           TERM  CREDITS_HOUR  SEATS_LEFT
CS111        Intro. to CS          1     3             50
CS211        Intro. to PS          2     3             50
CS244        Adcanced Application  4     3             50
CS311        Introduction to OOB   3     3             50
```

I've tried this query 
`SELECT DISTINCT C.COURSE_ID, C.COURSE_NAME, C.SEATS_LEFT
FROM  ENROLLMENT E, PREREQUISITE P, COURSES C
WHERE C.COURSE_ID NOT IN (SELECT COURSE_ID FROM ENROLLMENT WHERE STUDENT_ID = '444111110' AND GREADE !='U')
AND P.PREREQUISITE_COURSE_ID IN 
(SELECT COURSE_ID FROM ENROLLMENT WHERE STUDENT_ID = '444111110' AND GREADE !='W');`
But it return CS244 and CS311 for the student with id 444111110 while it should return CS311 only.
Also it does not return anything for students who didn't register any course or withdraw the first course only which is CS111.

is there is a possible way to make it check if the student took all the prerequisites courses not part of them ?
and is there is a way to fix that query for student who didn't enrolled in any courses to show them that they can register CS111 which it's prerequisite is NULL ?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to do your homework for you. It looks like you might have a legitimate question at the end, though. Please edit it to be more specific about the problem you are having. There is too much extra information in your post.

Comment: Well it wasn't homework, it was a problem I made up with my self to learn SQL better, I've created this database from scratch to connect it with java application. You just decided it was homework and you didn't even tried to help. I made the topic with 'Too much extra information' so the experts could tell if the design of the database was bad or not, also making it easy for who's going to answer me, since he got the schema and the data inside the tables it would be more clear. Anyway thanks for letting my hopes down, I've already came up with solution and posted it if someone needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COURSE_ID,COURSE_NAME,SEATS_LEFT FROM Courses WHERE Course_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT Course_ID FROM prerequisite WHERE PREREQUISITE_COURSE_ID IN 
    (SELECT Course_ID FROM Courses WHERE Course_ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT Course_ID FROM Enrollment WHERE Student_ID = '444111110' AND GREADE NOT IN ('U', 'F', 'W') ) ) ) AND Course_ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT Course_ID FROM Enrollment WHERE Student_ID = '444111110' AND (GREADE = 'U' OR GREADE NOT IN ('F', 'W') )  );
```

I would like to thank my Instructor for solving this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

,Try this

```
select course_ID, COURSE_NAME, SEATS_LEFT from Courses
where course_ID in (select course_ID from Enrollment where grade ='W')
or course id in (select course_id from Prerequisites where prerequisite_course_id in (select course_ID from Enrollment where grade != 'W')
```